# Exception handling over RMI

Tags: java, exception, rmi

I have a common problem where I would like to hear your opinion on what's the best way to do it.

Assume you have an application that runs on a distributed server system. Let's say frontend and backend server. Methods on the backend server a called through RMI.

The backend java process usually needs different libraries than the frontend java process. It's possible that a runtime exception occurs in the backend. The thrown exception is not caught by the backend and so it travels to the frontend server. The problem now is that the frontend doesn't know the exception because the package isn't in the classpath (e.g. EJBTransactionRolledBackException). Another exception is thrown - ClassNotFoundException. This makes it impossible to see where the execption occured because the stacktrace doesn't include the stack from the backend server. Another scenario I can think of is where the exception cannot be serialized.

How do you solve this problem? Can I somehow log any runtime exception that is thrown without having to build a try ... catch  and rethrow block?

Comment: I suggest to implement logging, for instance [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j) in your backend and frontend code. In case you have an exception, log it anyway and re-throw a custom (your own) exception when necessary from your `catch(Exception)` block.

Comment: This means that **every** method needs a try catch block where I catch all exceptions. Some of them have to be rethrown because they are custom exceptions. This is a lot code and looks really unclear. Is this really the only way?

Comment: It seems that your desing is bad. If the frontend server doenst know about exception class how would you like to handle it? My suggestion is to catch this exception and/or rethrow it when necessary. Theoreticaly it is possible to overwritte class loader so that is loads remote classes.

Comment: This is actually something very common. Think of a backend server that uses third party libraries. If only the backend server needs this library then there is no need to include it in the classpath of the frontend server. What if an exception from that library is thrown? You are saying that the frontend server should have every package the backend server has. That's a no go.

Comment: From my experience, when I need to implement some `not beautiful` approach, then it is a signal to reconsider the design. Good design does not require bad coding. For your case, you do not need to catch exceptions everywhere, but just declare methods which throw these exceptions, and catch/log/re-throw them on the top-level.

Comment: Once again to make sure this is 100% clear now: `RuntimeException` is thrown on backend server and not caught. The exception goes _up_ to the frontend server where then a `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown. **The stacktrace of the actual exception is lost!** This makes debugging impossible because I don't know where the exception on the backend server occurred.

Comment: What implementation of RMI are you talking about? The JDK implementation doesn't lose stack trace elements.

Comment: The stacktrace is lost because of the second ClassNotFoundException! All other _known_ exceptions don't lose the stacktrace.

Answer (score 5):

> Methods on the backend server are called through RMI.

Well **there's** your problem. :-)

Seriously, the easiest way to deal with this is probably to set the following property on the server:

```
-Dsun.rmi.server.exceptionTrace=true
```

This will give you the exception stack trace on the server side. It won't fix the `ClassNotFoundException` on the client side, but at least when that happens you know to dig through the server logs to find out more information.

Other useful RMI properties are documented here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html

Comment: Well, I didn't tell you that those methods are actually in an EJB. Unfortunately the property doesn't show the exception. Not sure whether it's my fault or not.

Comment: Ah. It makes a bit of sense that the RMI properties don't work in an EJB environment, because RMI calls are dispatched differently in that environment than in a "plain" RMI environment. Maybe there are some similar properties or settings, perhaps in the deployment descriptor? I don't really know EJB.

Comment: FYI, setting `-Dsun.rmi.server.exceptionTrace=true` on Glassfish 3.1.2.2 worked for me **for EJBs**. I compared the behaviour before and after: before the client received the exception but it did not appear in the server logs, after the client received the exception _and_ it appeared in the server logs. The client is an "Enterprise Application Client" invoking an EJB. The EJB method just throws an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 1):

- You could try the [codebase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/rmi/codebase.html) feature of RMI to get the server classes when needed. However, it's a pain to configure on JBoss
- You could install an interface layer based on [Dynamic Proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html) to do exception conversion (will not work in most EJB servers I think)
- If your server is a JBoss, you can use [EJB interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/interceptor/interceptor.html) to do exception conversion

I don't what other servers provide in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this question while looking for the answer myself. It turns out there is no good answer, but there are workarounds.

I built a simple rpc protocol using serialization over http, which has the same problem. You can find my half-clever solution to the problem here:

https://github.com/stickfigure/trivet/blob/master/src/main/java/com/voodoodyne/trivet/ExceptionalObjectInputStream.java

Basically, while deserializing the object stream, look for missing classes ending in "Exception" and swap the class descriptor with an exception class that *is* on the client. The upside is that nested stack traces are preserved as-is. The bad news is that because this replaces the exception class, that information is lost; each replaced exception becomes `ServerSideException`. Also any additional data besides the message is discarded. Usually it's not too hard to figure out what is going on from the stacktrace and message, but this code logs the original exception type just in case you need to dig it up.

I doubt you get enough hooks into the client proxy to apply this technique to RMI, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by this problem. 
Since we are using frontend and backend servers, why not define a message/result pair as the response . And the message do not need to be text, unique coding system is good enough, we can translate the codes into text messages at the frontend server with unified mechanism, similarly as what Spring Exception translator does.